# Particle ontology and quantum fluctuations

Tags: ontology, philosophy-of-physics, quantum-interpretations

I have been reading about ontologies in quantum physics recently and I came across Bohmian mechanics.
If I understood it correctly BM endorses Particle ontology.
Particle ontology claims that point-like particles that move continuously in time are the fundamental building blocks.
I know some people are trying to use field ontology for BM but I will ignore it here.

My question is, how does Particle ontology account for [quantum fluctuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_fluctuation) and [virtual particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle)? It seems to me these concepts require field ontology.

Thank you!

Comment: You did not understand it correctly. Bohmian particles are something distinct from quantum particles as used in "particle ontology" of QFT. Extensions of Bohmian mechanics to QFT are not fully worked out at this time. Since field and particle representations in QFT are mathematically equivalent they account for all those phenomena in the same way, which one to prefer is decided on more philosophical grounds, see e.g. [Baker, Against Field Interpretations of Quantum Field Theory](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/4350/) and references there.

Comment: Okay, could you please explain what does Particle ontology mean then?